# Real analysis : Problem related to inverse

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals, inverse-function

Let $f:[0,\infty)\rightarrow [0,\infty) $ be a continuous strictly increasing function and $g=f^{-1}$. Let $a,b>0$ and $a\neq b$. Then how $\displaystyle\int_{0}^af(x)dx+\int_0^bg(y)dy\geq ab.$
Any hint will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Description of the proof:** Reflect the graph of $g$ with respect to the line $y=x$ and then observe that the area below the graph of $f$ and the $x$ axis (from $0$ to $a$) and the area between the reflected graph of $g$ and the $y$ axis (between $0$ and $b$) have a sum, which is larger than the area $ab$ of the square, that is covered by those areas.

**A comment:** This trick is standard and it is used to prove Young's inequality, which is usually applied to prove Holder's inequality.

Comment: Your solution in impressive but is there any rigorous proof.

Comment: +1 very nice explanation, and thank you for the remark. However, if f stays completely below the symmetry line, it seems like the two areas cover vastly less than the area of the rectangle. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Ovi No, because if there is part of missing area between $f$ and the line $y=x$ (which happens when $f$ is below $y=x$), the area between the reflected graph of $g$ (Not $f$!) and the $y$ axis will cover it.

Comment: @ChandramauliChakraborty Indeed, I think that everything can be made rigorous if you stick to this idea and use Riemann sums to approximate your integrals.